# Mysql composite index with expression is not working

Tags: mysql

I have tried the following query to create index but it throws error

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX birthday_index ((date_format(birth_date, "%m-%d")))
```

[image]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel what should I do to make it work

Comment: You need MySQL 8.0.13 (at least)

Comment: I see, that might be it. Thanks